# eclipse - Unexpected error while loading repository template extensions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As the title, I'm getting this error at startup.

```
Unexpected error while loading repository template extensions
  Could not load repository template extension contributed by 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui' with connectorKind 'jira'
  Could not load repository template extension contributed by 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui' with connectorKind 'jira'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your eclispe version does not have the Atlassian JIRA connector installed.
[Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/IDEPLUGIN/Installing+the+Eclipse+Connector) is the Atlassian JIRA documentation.

Installing JIRA in eclipse:

1. Open the Eclipse software updates manager via 'Help', 'Install New Software'.
2. Click 'Add'. The 'Add Site' window will display.
3. Add this update site http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7 and click 'OK'.
4. The 'Available Software' screen will appear again. Select 'All Available Sites' in the 'Work with' dropdown list.
5. Select both 'Atlassian Connector' categories.
6. Click next and install.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Btw, I have Eclipse Luna. What should I do?